# How to get the Directed Graph Output using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

Trust you doing great !!!1

Trying to create a `directed graph` between airports using `AdjacencyList`  shown in [YT Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWNEl4HE2OE) using `Map function` in Node.js and ran the below code in online editor `pramp.com`,problem is why Map is showing the output as `Empty`...It should show up a Map like this ,also if you can explain what this line of code does `routes.forEach(route => addEdge(...route))` why `3 dots` and fat arrow `=>`

[image]

Question is is this problem with online editor `Pramp.com` ? I dont want to use `VSCode` hence using online editor

```
            //The Data

            const airports = 'PHX BKK OKC JFK LAX MEX EZE HEL LOS LAP LIM'.split(' ');

            const routes = [

            ['PHX','LAX'],
            ['PHX','JFK'],
            ['JFK','OKC'],
            ['JFK','HEL'],
            ['MEX','LAX'],
            ['MEX','BKK'],
            ['MEX','LIM'],
            ['MEX','EZE'],
            ['LIM','BKK'],

            ];

            //The Graph

            const adjacencyList = new Map();

            //add-node
            function addnode(airport){

            adjacencyList.set(airport,[]);

            //Add edge,undirected
            function addEdge(origin,destination){
            adjacencyList.get(origin).push(destination);
            adjacencyList.get(destination).push(origin);

            }

            //Create the Graph
            airports.forEach(addNode);
            routes.forEach(route => addEdge(...route))



            }

            console.log(adjacencyList);
```

In `Pramp` editor i see this

[image]

Many Thanks In advance

Carolyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ellipsis (...) is the spread operator. It takes an array, for example [origin, destination] and basically turns it into two vars origin, destination. Calling

```
addEdge(...[origin,destination])
```

is like calling

```
addEdge([origin,destination][0], [origin,destination][1])
```

Which is the same as

```
addEdge(origin,destination)
```

The "fat arrow" operator is a lambda (anonymous function) definition.

```
(a,b) => { console.log(a, b) }
```

is the same as

```
function (a,b) { console.log(a, b) }
```

Its just a shorter way to define functions without names. Usually simple ons that are given as parameters. In this case to the forEach call.